# What are these plants?

Tags: identification

What is this?   It had blue or purple flowers in early summer

[image]

Comment: Which is it: blue or purple? What did the flowers look like? Where in the world did you find this plant, and what conditions was it growing in?

Comment: Small blue flowers I think, in early summer.  London UK.  Shady conditions in garden.   Photo taken  29 August 2017.

Comment: Are the leaves rough and unpleasant to touch?

Comment: I would say yes.  Tomorrow I will go out and touch them to be sure.

Comment: Need to have scale reference, please?  If the ivy is a normal ivy these leaves are huge?

Comment: Were these flowers spikes or  perhaps droopy looking?

Comment: The large leaves are a bit rough, more than six inches in length.

Answer (score 3):

On the assumption the leaves are rough and unpleasant to handle, it's Pentaglottis sempervirens, common name green alkanet, a common perennial 'weed' in the UK, and difficult to dig out or eradicate (because of its deep, yet fragile roots) once established. Image and info here: [Green Alkanet (Alkanet, Evergreen Bugloss)](http://www.thetortoisetable.org.uk/plant-database/viewplants/?plant=371#.WaXnZyrTXo4) .

Comment: I'm not sure about the identification. This plant remember me something..

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi - reminds you of something? Digitalis purpureum or Borago officinalis possibly - its not Digitalis if it has rough leaves, and Borago, (which it could conceivably be), is only an annual - without flowers, hard to be 100% between alkanet and borage, but I'm betting its alkanet, given where the OP lives

Comment: I was wondering if it could be a campanula?

Comment: I think it is green alkanet.  I looked at pictures and seem to recall the small blue flowers.